# Unbound Variable in Scheme

Tags: variables, functional-programming, scheme, lisp, scope

I know what I want to do, I am having trouble getting there. I am looking for some guidance. I am more or less forcing what I want done and there has to be a better way than the way I am trying to create this function. **I currently get an unbound variable error right where I call `(set! nadj)` and `(set! count)`.**

I am trying to make a function where the user inputs a sentence. If more than 25% of that sentence consists of adjectives the function returns false.

This is what I have so far:

```
(define OK
  (lambda (x)
    (cond
      ((adj? (car x))
       (set! count (+ count 1)))
      ((not (adj? (car x))       
            (set! nadj (+ nadj 1))))
      ((not (null? (OK (cdr x)))))                  
      ((null? x)
       (set! sum (+ nadj count)))
      ;;(set! div (/ count sum))
      ;;(* 100 div)
      ;;(< div 25))
      ((else  #f)))))
```

What I am trying to do is make a counter for the words that are an adjective and a counter for the words that are not. Then I am trying to add all of the words up and divide them by the amount of words that were adjectives. I then want to multiply that by 100 and return true if it is less than 25%. I am not looking for an answer, more or less I just want some guidance.

Here is the `adj?` function if you need to see it.

```
(define adjectives '(black brown fast hairy hot quick red slow))
(define adj?
  (lambda(x)
   (if ( member x adjectives) #t #f)))
```

**I am sure this isn't normal Scheme notation. I program a lot in C++ and Java and I am having a hard time transitioning into Scheme.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are familiar with the **named let**, but this comes in handy here:

```
(define (OK x)
  (let loop ((x x) (adj 0) (nadj 0)) ; named let
    (cond
      ((null? x)      (< (/ adj (+ adj nadj)) 0.25))
      ((adj? (car x)) (loop (cdr x) (+ 1 adj) nadj))
      (else           (loop (cdr x) adj (+ 1 nadj))))))
```

This is a convenient notation for the following, equivalent code:

```
(define (OK x)
  (define (loop x adj nadj)
    (cond
      ((null? x)      (< (/ adj (+ adj nadj)) 0.25))
      ((adj? (car x)) (loop (cdr x) (+ 1 adj) nadj))
      (else           (loop (cdr x) adj (+ 1 nadj)))))
  (loop x 0 0))
```

so basically we define an internal function, and what is a loop in a language such as C++ and Java becomes a recursive call (and to add to the confusion, the procedure that gets called recursively is sometimes called `loop`, as in my example). Since the call is done in tail position, this is just as efficient in Scheme as a classic loop in the languages you mentioned.

Variable assignments are replaced by modifying the parameters of the recursive call, i.e. you usually find no `set!` procedures in such a simple case.

**EDIT** an example implementation using `set!`:

```
(define OK
  (let ((adj 0) (nadj 0))
    (lambda (x)
      (cond
        ((null? x) (< (/ adj (+ adj nadj)) 0.25))
        (else      (if (adj? (car x))
                       (set! adj (+ 1 adj))
                       (set! nadj (+ 1 nadj)))
                   (OK (cdr x)))))))
```

Comment: Oh, ok now! So, let is essentially creating a location for adj and nadj then placing values into those locations. Then once "loop" is called it evaluates the body of the call.

Comment: Yes. The "locations" are the parameters of the function. The problem in your initial code is that you never created the locations (with `define` or `let`), which is why you got your error message. If you're interested I can show you how you should have coded this, in order to compare with my code.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. Thank you so much! I have spent the last four or so hours trying to think of a better solution than the one I currently have and I was getting nowhere fast.

Comment: Yes, if you don't mind showing me how I should have coded this that would be great!

Comment: Thank you again for your help. It is greatly appreciated. I have learned a lot more in these past 30 or so minutes than I have reading my book for the past few hours. Seeing these examples makes a lot more sense.

Comment: That's great. Yes it is incredibly important to read good, idiomatic code (for any language you want to learn, but especially if the new language is somehow different from what you used before). Therefore your book *should* have a lot of useful code.

Comment: @MipsMoreLikeWhips And to be clear, this isn't really different (except for type declarations) from a language like C or Java, where you can't jut write `adj++;` somewhere without having `ìnt adj;` (or `int adj=0;`, etc.) somewhere earlier.  You must declare the variables before you try to do something with them.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in stating that your solution is not idiomatic Scheme - we try really hard to avoid mutating variables, all those `set!` operations are frowned upon: we don't really need them.  A more idiomatic solution would be to pass along the counters as parameters, as demonstrated in @uselpa's answer. His solution uses explicit recursion via a named `let`.

We can go one step further, though - the true spirit of functional programming is to reuse existing higher-order procedures and compose them in such a way that they solve our problems. I don't know which Scheme interpreter you're using, but in Racket the `OK` procedure can be expressed as simply as this:

```
(define (OK x)         ; assuming a non-empty list
  (< (/ (count adj? x) ; count the number of adjectives
        (length x))    ; divide by the total number of words
     0.25))            ; is it less than 25%?
```

If your Scheme interpreter doesn't provide a `count` procedure import it from [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#count); also it's very easy to implement your own - again, this is in the spirit of functional programming: we want to build generic procedures that are useful in their own right, and easily reused and composed in other contexts:

```
(define (count pred lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (counter 0))
    (cond ((null? lst) counter)
          ((pred (car lst)) (loop (cdr lst) (+ 1 counter)))
          (else (loop (cdr lst) counter)))))
```

Playing Devil's advocate it's possible to fix your function using an imperative style, as long as we define the variables first (by the way, that was causing the "unbound variable" error) - for example, place a `let` before the looping function: think of it as a variable declaration that happens before the recursion starts. Also notice that the empty list case *must* appear first, to avoid accessing an element in an empty list, and don't forget to advance the recursion at each step. This is ugly, but should work:

```
(define (OK x) ; assuming a non-empty list
  ; declare the counters outside the function
  (let ((adj 0) (nadj 0))
    ; looping function
    (let loop ((x x))
      (cond
         ; is the list empty?
        ((null? x)
         ; is the number of adjectives less than 25%?
         (< (/ adj (+ adj nadj)) 0.25))
         ; is current element an adjective?
        ((adj? (car x))
         ; increment adj counter
         (set! adj (+ adj 1))
         ; always advance recursion
         (loop (cdr x)))
         ; is current element anything other than an adjective?
        (else       
         ; increment nadj counter
         (set! nadj (+ nadj 1))
         ; always advance recursion
         (loop (cdr x)))))))
```

Comment: @MipsMoreLikeWhips your attempted solution can be fixed, see my answer above. Even so, there's a more idiomatic way to solve this problem, also see my second implementation

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help again @Óscar López. I know the way I am doing it is ugly. I was stuck on one way of thinking. So, in your second solution where you reuse higher-order procedures you can just pass the counters as parameters? That is very useful to know too. It would have saved me much time haha.

Comment: @MipsMoreLikeWhips make an extra effort, remember: Scheme is not C++, avoid `set!` and embrace recursion - even better, adopt an style that composes existing procedures to solve your problems, that's the correct way of thinking when programming in Lisp.

Comment: That makes sense. You're right, Scheme is a totally different language and to get better in that language I need to think in that language. Thank you again @Óscar López.

Comment: localized and encapsulated mutation is fine, IMO (in the absence of non-local exits of course, but then it's not localized and encapsulated, in such cases). the language [has `do` after all](http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/html/reference/for.html?q=do#%28form._%28%28lib._scheme/private/more-scheme..ss%29._do%29%29), for a good reason. Restructuring code just for the sake of avoiding `set!` can in some cases make it less readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an unbound variable, even a global one. Variables refer to locations; setting a variable that doesn't exist anywhere is impossible:

<sup>**(set! a 1)**

;Unbound variable: a           *; a doesn't refer to any location yet*

**(define a)**

;Value: a

**(list a)**

;Unassigned variable: a       *; now it does, but it hasn't been assigned a value yet*

**(set! a 1)**

;Value: a

**(list a)**

;Value: (1)

**(set! a 2)**

;Value: 1

**(list a)**

;Value: (2)</sup>

There's nothing wrong with *localized* and *encapsulated* mutation. Setting a global variable is by definition not localized.

You should have created *local bindings* (locations) for the variables you intended to use. The basic iteration [built-in form `do`](http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/html/reference/for.html?q=do#%28form._%28%28lib._scheme/private/more-scheme..ss%29._do%29%29) does it for you:

```
(define (OK x) 
  (do ((adj 0) (nadj 0))
      ((null? x)          ; loop termination condition
         (< (/ adj (+ adj nadj))
            0.25))        ; return value form
    ; loop body
    (if (adj? (car x))  
        (set! adj (+ adj 1))
        ; else
        (set! nadj (+ nadj 1)))
    ; some other statements maybe...
    ))
```

Just another option that sometimes might come handy. Of course the most idiomatic Scheme code is using named *`let`* construct. It will also force you to refactor a spaghetti code that you *might* otherwise write using `do`. Don't. :)